# Unix cut: Print same Field twice

Tags: shell, unix, sed, cut

Say I have file -  a.csv

```
ram,33,professional,doc
shaym,23,salaried,eng
```

Now I need this output (pls dont ask me why)

```
ram,doc,doc,
shayam,eng,eng,
```

I am using cut command

```
cut -d',' -f1,4,4 a.csv
```

But the output remains

```
ram,doc
shyam,eng
```

That means **cut** can only print **a Field just one time**. I need to print the same field twice or *n* times. 
**Why do I need this ?** (Optional to read)
Ah. It's a long story. I have a file like this

```
#,#,-,-
#,#,#,#,#,#,#,-
#,#,#,-
```

I have to covert this to

```
#,#,-,-,-,-,-
#,#,#,#,#,#,#,-
#,#,#,-,-,-,-
```

Here each '#' and '-' refers to different numerical data. Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? Why can you only use `cut` or `sed`?

Comment: Do the output lines have to end with a comma?

Comment: Do you mean that every line should have the same number of fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't print the same field twice. `cut` prints a selection of fields (or characters or bytes) in order. See [Combining 2 different cut outputs in a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47048/combining-2-different-cut-outputs-in-a-single-command) and [Reorder fields/characters with cut command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47075/reorder-fields-characters-with-cut-command) for some very similar requests.

The right tool to use here is awk, if your CSV doesn't have quotes around fields.

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '{print $1, $4, $4}'
```

If you don't want to use awk (why? what strange system has `cut` and `sed` but no `awk`?), you can use sed (still assuming that your CSV doesn't have quotes around fields). Match the first four comma-separated fields and select the ones you want in the order you want.

```
sed -e 's/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\1,\4,\4/'
```

Comment: This is a better solution in awk / and the sed solution provided by Jens

Comment: One thing about awk and range printing is its slowness compared to cut. Would be nice to call cut twice for every line.

Comment: @JohnJiang True, awk is typically slower than sed which is slower than specialized tools like cut. You'd only notice for very large files (millions of records). There's a cut+paste solution in one of the threads I link which is probably faster for very large files.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/,.*,/,/; s/\(,.*\)/\1\1,/' a.csv
ram,doc,doc,
shaym,eng,eng,
```

What this does:

- Replace everything between the first and last comma with just a comma
- Repeat the last ",something" part and tack on a comma. Voilà!

Assumptions made:

- You want the first field, then twice the last field
- No escaped commas within the first and last fields

Why do you need exactly this output? :-)

Comment: Am I attaching the scope of the problem in my question.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, `cut` doesn't support field repetition.

You can combine `cut` and `sed`, for example if the repeated element is at the end:

```
< a.csv cut -d, -f1,4 | sed 's/,[^,]*$/&&,/'
```

Output:

```
ram,doc,doc,
shaym,eng,eng,
```

#### Edit

To make the repetition variable, you could do something like this (assuming you have coreutils available):

```
n=10
rep=$(seq $n | sed 's:.*:\&:' | tr -d '\n')
< a.csv cut -d, -f1,4 | sed 's/,[^,]*$/'"$rep"',/'
```

Output:

```
ram,doc,doc,doc,doc,doc,doc,doc,doc,doc,doc,
shaym,eng,eng,eng,eng,eng,eng,eng,eng,eng,eng,
```

Answer (score 1):

using perl:

```
perl -F, -ane 'chomp($F[3]);$a=$F[0].",".$F[3].",".$F[3];print $a."\n"' your_file
```

using sed:

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),.*,\(.*\)/\1,\2,\2/g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but instead of adding all the columns to awk, I just used (to duplicate the 2nd column):

`awk -v OFS='\t' '$2=$2"\t"$2' # for tab-delimited files`

For CSVs you can just use

`awk  -F , -v OFS=, '$2=$2","$2'`